# Error when trying to restart my app by pressing home button?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

In my android app I have few Tabs .The app runs fine , but whenever I press home on the second tab of any Tabhost and restart it back by pressing home (recent items ) it crashes and a nullpointer at :

```
   04-28 15:47:06.177: W/System.err(25731): java.lang.NullPointerException
   04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):     at android.widget.TabWidget.setCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:339)
   04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):     at android.widget.TabWidget.focusCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:363)
   04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
    04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
   04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):     at com.cuelearn.main.ChapterTab.onResume(ChapterTab.java:82)
   04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
  04-28 15:47:06.237: W/System.err(25731):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
```

And then:

```
   04-28 15:47:06.177: W/System.err(25731): java.lang.NullPointerException
  04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):  at android.widget.TabWidget.setCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:339)
  04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):  at android.widget.TabWidget.focusCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:363)
   04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
  04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
   04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):     at com.cuelearn.main.ChapterTab.onResume(ChapterTab.java:82)
   04-28 15:47:06.207: W/System.err(25731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
   04-28 15:47:06.237: W/System.err(25731):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
   04-28 15:47:06.827: E/AndroidRuntime(25731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  04-28 15:47:06.827: E/AndroidRuntime(25731): java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-28 15:47:06.827: E/AndroidRuntime(25731):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
 04-28 15:47:06.827: E/AndroidRuntime(25731):   at android.widget.TabWidget.dispatchDraw(TabWidget.java:271)
  04-28 15:47:06.827: E/AndroidRuntime(25731):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
  04-28 15:47:06.827: E/AndroidRuntime(25731):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
```

I am a newbie to this Please help me?I have to do this last task to complete my app so Please help?

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
//  addTabs();

  tabHost=getTabHost();

    tabHost.clearAllTabs();

      try{

           tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("All").setContent(new Intent(this, ChTable.class)

                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));



        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("New").setContent(
                new Intent(this, ChapterNew.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabbed);


        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height =35;

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height =35;


}
    catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
// TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

Comment: have you used any static reference?

Comment: I dont know I am noob .How can i use one .will that help here??

Comment: check line 82 in your `ChapterTab` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabbed);
It looks like your 'tabbed' is not defined or valid.